# Why must the wsdl file be in WEB-INF (in Apache CXF)?

Tags: soap, cxf

In the wsdl_first sample of Apache CXF the pom file puts the wsdl file in WEB-INF/. Also all the xml files and the wsdl file in src/main/resources ends up in WEB-INF/classes, because they are in src/main/resources.

I deploy the webapp in tomcat.

My question is: when I remove the wsdl file from WEB-INF and the xml files and the wsdl file from WEB-INF/classes (and restart Tomcat), the webapp still works.  Why does the pom file put the wsdl file explicitly in WEB-INF? And why are the xml files and the wsdl file in WEB-INF/classes?

In src/main/webapp there are web.xml and cxf-servlet.xml. They end up in WEB-INF/. When I remove them, things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So remember a WSDL is the official definition of a service interface. In other words if you want to create a client for a SOAP service you need a WSDL. You can use this WSDL to then generate code artifacts for the client. It is almost exactly similar to generating a server from a WSDL.

Now the WEB-INF folder is published and when the WSDL is in there it is published too. This will allow clients to get to the WSDL. However the WSDL is not needed for the service to run. Thus we can remove the WSDL.

You would typically remove the WSDL when you secure a service against public browsing. This will remove the ability for anyone just to get hold of the service definition.

Remember the WSDL is just a definition used to generate artefacts in various languages such as Java, .Net etc.

However it is not required for a SOAP server or client to run. Just for code generation.